# Obtaining a "gitlab runner token"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-runner

I a gitlab repository that I would like to set up a gitlab runner for. In the documentation it states that I need to register the runner using the "registration token" from the gitlab website in the repository settings.

However, after issuing the "gitlab-runner start" command, I still need to create a config.toml file with the url and a "runner token" in order to be able to run the gitlab-runner run command, which I need to run a number of commands upon a push on a specified branch.

I am not sure where to find this "runner token". In the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) it only states that the runner token is different from the registration token, but not where to obtain it.

I would highly appreciate any kind of help or suggestions.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/ `Obtain a token:  ... For a project-specific runner, go to Settings > CI/CD and expand the Runners section`. Let `gitlab-runner register` edit `config.toml`, don't do it by hand.

Comment: @KamilCuk I ran gitlab-runner register with the registration token i acquired from the CI CD runner section but it did not create a config.toml file anywhere. Maybe it was not created in the default path?

Answer (score 0):

The config.toml was not being created in the proper folder, see [here](https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/how-i-solved-new-runner-has-not-connected-yet-in-gitlab-ci/)